# Mutation is not working - Flutter & GraphQL

Tags: flutter, graphql, mutation

I connected my app with graphql, the queries are working just fine and I'm able to get data from the API, but somehow the mutations are not working at all. My mytation is a simple login function, where you put login and password of an existing user. Every time I run it, onCompleted returns null value, instead of JSON with token. Later I've checked if the mutation passed anything to database, but it didn't. Is there a way to fix it?

my code:

```
final String loginQuery = """
mutation loginUser(\$email: String!, \$password: String!){
 login(email: \$email, password: \$password){}
}
""";
```

Login widget: after pressing the button, Text widget should show the result of mutation.

```
Widget mutation() {
    return Mutation(
        options: MutationOptions(
          update: (Cache cache, QueryResult result) {
            return cache;
          },
          onCompleted: (resultData) {
            print('on completed $resultData');
          },
          documentNode: gql(loginQuery),
        ),
        builder: (RunMutation runMutation, QueryResult result) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('login'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    runMutation(
                        {"email": "mockuser@gmail.com", "password": "123456"});
                    print(result.data);
                  }),
              Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Text('Result  \n ${result?.data?.toString()}'))
            ],
          );
        });
  }
```

Comment: api mutation tested separately? does it work from postman?

Comment: yes, works fine from postman

Comment: compare raw network request details with postman

Comment: after debugging I noticed it returns 422 error, and then GraphQL Error: "expected at least one definition, found }: Undefined location"; any idea what could cause it?

Comment: and it works in postman? for **exactly** the same query? ... no sub-field requested ... mutation def? return type? if not simple type then some property of that should be requested .... `mutation ...login( .. vars ) { HERE }`

Comment: thank you, the curly brackets after login(...)  were unnecessary, I've run it in postman and it clearly showed the error there

Answer (score -2):

Try using,

```
onError: (err) {
          print(err.graphqlErrors);
         },
```

after **onCompleted**.
This will show you the error (if there's any).